# Discord js Add reaction to a bot message

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I've been created my own discord bot but i have this error for this code:

```html
    message.channel.send(":apple:***SONDAGE :apple:\n "+choix1+" ou "+""+choix2+"***")
      .then(function (message) {
          message.react("")
          message.react("")
         message.pin()
          message.delete()
       });
```

It's send a message to the channel and add reaction, and in my console i have this error:

```html
(node:11728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
(node:11728) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:11728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those aren't error, those are warning. As it is said, you don't check when your promise is rejected.
You should use .catch() after .then() in case it get rejected.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise/catch

Try :

```
message.channel.send(":apple:***SONDAGE :apple:\n "+choix1+" ou "+""+choix2+"***")
            .then(function (message) {
              message.react("")
              message.react("")
              message.pin()
              message.delete()
            }).catch(function() {
              //Something
             });
```

Answer (score 3):

On top of the previous things that the other answers have mentioned, functions like `message.react(...)` all return Promises, so for example the message might get deleted before the react/pin promises are resolved.

If you want things to happen in order you need to have a long `.then(...).then(...).then(...)` chain, or alternatively you could use async/await. Here's an async/await example:

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  const sentMessage = await message.channel.send("my message");
  await sentMessage.react("");
  await sentMessage.react("");
  await sentMessage.pin();
  await sentMessage.delete();
});
```

If you want to do any error handling on failures, you can wrap the await stuff in a try/catch block:

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  try {
    const sentMessage = await message.channel.send("my message");
    await sentMessage.react("");
    await sentMessage.react("");
    await sentMessage.pin();
    await sentMessage.delete();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
});
```

Further reading:

- [TextChannel.send(message)](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)
- [Message.react(emoji)](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=react)
- [Message.pin()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=pin)
- [Message.delete()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, you do `message.delete()`, but you want to add reactions. When a message is deleted the bot can't add reactions. Just remove the `message.delete()` and no error will come.

Answer (score 0):

Now on version 14 some things has changed a bit

The `message` and `interaction` events are now removed. You've to use `messageCreate` and `interactionCreate` instead.

So the code would like something like this...

```js
client.on(Events.MessageCreate, async (message) => {
  try {
    if (message.channel.id === channel) {
      await message.react('');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

Further reading:

- [Events](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#events)
- [Reacting to messages](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reacting-to-messages)